# STM32 as a MIDI device (I'm lost)

Tags: stm32, midi

I have an STM32F723.  I'm trying to configure it so that my computer recognizes it as a MIDI device via USB.

I searched the internet for examples, and read up on USB and MIDI.

However, I'm lost in all this flow of information.

I use CubeMX and CubeIDE, do you have a SIMPLE example of configuration?

For the moment I just want Windows to recognize my card as a MIDI device.

I have managed to get Windows to recognize my card as an audio device but I don't know what else I need to do to implement MIDI.

I think I need to add MIDI files with functions to implement MIDI through USB, but I don't know what files, I see everything on the internet I'm lost.

Comment: This is absolutely not going to be a simple project unless you can find somebody who's already done it. How is your C programming ability?

Comment: Many people have already made MIDI projects on other series of STM32 F4, F0, F1 cards ...
But they do very complex and advanced things which makes their code unreadable and I get lost in it.
So for now I just want to start by having my card detected as a MIDI device, I think it can't be very hard, but I'm lost :( My skills in embedded programming in C are very basic ...

Comment: Why do you assume it is not very hard, if other people made very complex code to make the device act as MIDI endpoint?

Comment: From scratch, you would need to make both, device driver for PC system and USB MIDI device in the MCU. It would be better to study the complex code.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič No that incorrect; operating systems do have drivers for standard MIDI class drivers, just like they have drivers for standard mass storage class drivers.

Comment: I think I expressed myself badly.
When I said complex programs, I meant that they put a lot of functionality into their projects, so it makes the code very complex to understand, whereas I only want the core of the program "Make Windows recognize my card as a MIDI device" and I think that's not very complex. 
But I'm lost

Comment: But it is very complex. Again you need to craft the USB descriptors to say to PC that the connected device is a MIDI device, and you need to have USB MIDI device class implementation on STM32 that needs to run under the USB stack provided by ST HAL. Easy right? I have not searched but I know that many years ago someone said on some forums that it was possible to take CDC class driver and modify it into MIDI class driver.

Answer (score 4):

The MIDI class is not supported by the STMCube HAL but it is well known and implemented, you just need to google a bit.

I am currently doing a stm32 project with midi as well and I am using these two projects as reference:

- https://github.com/spectran/stm32f103-usb-midi
- https://github.com/ripxorip/stm32_usb_midi
- https://github.com/arneboe/con.trol

Both have the midi usb class there one for stm32f1xx and another for stm32f4xx. For those I had made it work in a stm32f411CE (Blackpill board) with cont.trol configuring first the project as USB Audio class and later adding the MIDI class and initializing MIDI class Instead of AUDIO.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no simple way. The F7 HAL for USB device does not implement a MIDI device class. Feel free to use CDC class as a base for building your own MIDI device class.

Comment: I know that HAL doesn't implement a MIDI class and that it has to be created, I was just wondering if there were some simple enough examples of MIDI classes?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sebseb7/stm32-midi-demo/blob/master/midi/usb.c is worth a try.

This is a midi audio class configuration with midi included.
I haven't tried it yet. I nave a midi audio class device generated by the STM32CubeIde and that is showing up as a 'STM Audio Device' in my device manager when I plug it in.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you my implementation of the midi driver, which is compatible with last STM32CubeMX: https://github.com/Hypnotriod/midi-box-stm32
There you will find the guide about changes in the generated code you need to do to make everything working.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of a MIDI implementation on an STM32 [here](https://github.com/ScherbakovAl/midi_for_stm32h7).

Here you can trace the commit history and understand what needs to be changed to turn the STM32 into a MIDI device.

Comment: Hi, If you are affiliated to the link in your answer, please [edit] your answer to disclose that affiliation as required by [this site rule](/help/promotion), to prevent possible deletion as spam (undisclosed promotion). Thanks.